# Distcp Mismatch in length of source

Tags: hadoop, distcp

I am facing issue while executing *distcp* command between two different *hadoop* clusters,

> Caused by: java.io.IOException: Mismatch in length of
>   source:hdfs://ip1/xxxxxxxxxx/xxxxx and
>   target:hdfs://nameservice1/xxxxxx/.distcp.tmp.attempt_1483200922993_0056_m_000011_2

I tried using -pb and -skipcrccheck:

```
hadoop distcp -pb -skipcrccheck -update hdfs://ip1/xxxxxxxxxx/xxxxx hdfs:///xxxxxxxxxxxx/ 

hadoop distcp -pb  hdfs://ip1/xxxxxxxxxx/xxxxx hdfs:///xxxxxxxxxxxx/ 

hadoop distcp -skipcrccheck -update hdfs://ip1/xxxxxxxxxx/xxxxx hdfs:///xxxxxxxxxxxx/
```

but nothing seems to be working.

Any solutions please.

Comment: versions of the clusters are the same? I think there is an incompatibility between the versions of the two clusters. Basing on _Hadoop the Definitive Guide_ try: `If the two clusters are running incompatible versions of HDFS, then you can use the
webhdfs protocol to distcp between them:
% hadoop distcp webhdfs://namenode1:50070/foo webhdfs://namenode2:50070/foo`

Comment: The versions(cdh5.8.2) are same ,event tried with webhdfs but stil the same error.

Comment: Does it always fail for everything, or sometimes for specific files? And does it fail like this in 2 directions or just from cluster 1 to cluster 2?

Comment: It fails if there are any bad/corrupt files,yes it can fail in both the directions cluster 1 to cluster 2 and vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue with distcp between two Hadoop clusters of exactly the same version. For me it turned out to be due to some files in one of the source directories being still open. Once I ran distcp for each source directory individually I was able to find that was the case - it worked fine for all but the one directory with the open files and only for those files. Of course it's hard to tell at first blush.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was resolved by performing copyToLocal from cluster1 one to local linux fs and copyFromLocal to cluster2.

Answer (score -1):

1. Check source file stats, use command:

   ```
   hdfs fsck hdfs://xxxxxxxxxxx
   ```
2. If the source file is not close, use this command to close it:

   ```
   hdfs debug recoverLease -path hdfs://xxxxxxx
   ```
3. `hadoop distcp -bandwidth 15 -m 50 -pb hdfs://xxxxxx hdfs://xxxxxx`