# Size of File changes after writing through a map reduce job

Tags: mapreduce, pyspark, hdfs

I wrote a tar file on HDFS through pyspark, using saveAsHadoopFile.

when i do hdfs dfs -du -s -h on the written files it shows it in 1:14 ratio of file size and replication file size.
After some time the file size increases and the ratio comes down to 1:3(desirable).

The problem is that,i can copy the files immediately after writing but cant distcp the files as it gives mismatch in length error.
[stackoverflow link of error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41542844/distcp-mismatch-in-length-of-source?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)
however after sometime when size goes back to actual size i am able to do a distcp.

Comment: You should really share a [mcve] (at least the code).Writing `tar` (are you sure about that) in Spark is definitely not something usual.

Comment: After writing the file the hdfs dfs - du - s -h returns **500gb 7tb** where the actual size should be **1.6TB.**
After sometime the size readjusts itself to **1.6TB 4.8TB**